# How to access Alchemy/C functions from Haxe

Tags: c, flash, haxe, swc, alchemy

I am writing a project in Haxe targeting flash. We have licensed a library written in C, which is being provided as an Alchemy-compiled SWC.

I can figure out the compilation options (I think), my concern is more things like:

- What do I import?
- Will the functions just be available or do I need to "load" them?
- What are the functions going to be called?
- Do I need to convert the arguments from one datatype to another? etc.

I have no prior experience with Flash or Alchemy.

Thanks!